# Making a tag suggestion using jQuery chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery chosen plugin https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/ to make my select form fields pretty. Here is the demo page for chosen plugin https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

I was thinking if it is possible to make tags like stackoverflow using chosen plugin because some of its feature looks alike. I am also like to know how do i use chosen with ajax to add tag suggestions.

I could use one of those jquery tags out there but i would like to know if i can do it using chosen so i don't need to add another script with my page.

Let me know if you need to know anything more.

Comment: @ChrisEdwards: no! I will provide the solution here if i work on it further.

Comment: @ChrisEdwards: take a look at [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587295/making-a-tag-suggestion-using-jquery-chosen-plugin#14536904).

Answer (score 3):

All that you have to do is to modify the select box with an [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). Than use :

`$("#form_field").trigger("list:updated");`

to tell "chosen" that the list has been updated.

Comment: You need to explain more please

Comment: I need to make a tag sugession like we see in stackoverflow.com when we write a question. In chosen plugin the multiple selection box is works kinda same. I just need to add it on a textbox rather then select box. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all of what you ask is possible. [From my answer to "Is there a way to dynamically ajax add elements through jquery chosen plugin?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14536897/504611):

> Take a look at the neat **[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/)** plugin, which is **based on [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) itself and supports remote data sources (aka AJAX data) and infinite scrolling**.

Answer (score 1):

The [koenpunt fork](https://github.com/koenpunt/chosen) of chosen has the functionality you want. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683098/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-ajax-add-elements-through-jquery-chosen-plugin/17429827#17429827)