# jQuery not recognizing dynamically-inserted DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Yet another "dynamically change select options based on parent option selected" question.

I have the select values changing dynamically - but after my rails render of the child select - I lose the Chosen styling (the jQuery Chosen plugin) and I cannot operate on this newly injected element.

Here is where the code is *right now* - it's gone through dozens of iterations -

```
$('#vendor_block').on('change', '#vendor_name', function(){
      overlay.show();
      var v = $(this).val();
      vndr_json = {};
      vndr_json["v"] = v;
      $.ajax({
          type : "GET",
          url : "/purchaseorders/upd_vndr_locs",
          data : vndr_json,
          success: function(res) {
            overlay.hide();
            // console.log(typeof(res),res);
            jQuery("#vndrAddrOpts").html(res);
          }
      });
      $("#vendor_addresses").chosen(); // WHY DON'T YOU RENDER CHOSEN BOX?!
  });
```

I get this new select box on my page - and I want to fire an event when it changes, but the DOM has already loaded, so it doesn't "see" this element I'm guessing.

Also - the Chosen plugin doesn't render on the element.  Not sure why - probably the same reason.

I'm using jQuery's .on() like every post on SO says I should.  But it doesn't "reload" the elements inside this parent (and 'vendor_block' is the parent div of 'vendor_name' and 'vendor_addresses').

You can see the difference in the select boxes here:

[image: Chosen box (top) with non-Chosen box (bottom)]

Any help would be great?

UPDATE:

Adding before and after HTML :

```
<div id="vndrAddrOpts">
    <select class="chzn-select vndrLocs span12" id="vendor_addresses" name="vendor_addresses"><option value="">Select Location</option></select>
</div>
```

That is the raw HTML - but Chosen does the following when the DOM loads:

```
<div id="vendor_addresses_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single chzn-with-drop chzn-container-active" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;" title=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>Select Location</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="vendor_addresses_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected highlighted" style="">Select Location</li></ul></div></div>
```

This is all fine and well - this is what's supposed to happen.

This is the raw HTML after the select box has been injected:

```
<div id="vndrAddrOpts">
    <select class="chzn-select vndrLocs span12" id="vendor_addresses" name="vendor_addresses"><option value="">Select Location</option></select>
</div>
```

And here is the rendered box - sans Chosen stuff.

```
<select class="chzn-select vndrLocs span12" id="vendor_addresses" name="vendor_addresses"><option value="">Select Location</option><option value="532757b4963e6505bc000003">Honolulu</option>
<option value="532768d0963e6505bc000004">Waipahu</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here :

[Is there a way to dynamically ajax add elements through jquery chosen plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683098/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-ajax-add-elements-through-jquery-chosen-plugin)

I actually was approaching this problem in an overly complex way - trying to inject and element instead of just starting with the element and adding options to it.

My AJAX looks like this now:

```
       $.ajax({
          type : "GET",
          url : "/purchaseorders/upd_vndr_locs",
          data : vndr_json,
          success: function(res) {
            overlay.hide();
            var va = $('#vendor_addresses');
            // console.log(typeof(res),res);
            for (var i=0; i < res.length; i++) {
              va.append(
              $('<option></option>')
                .val(res[i].id)
                .html(res[i].name)
              );  
            }
            va.trigger("liszt:updated");
            // jQuery("#vndrAddrOpts").html(res);
          }
        });
```

So instead of even worrying about rebuilding the chosen element from an injected element - we just use the built-in "updated" trigger and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think the chosen method is firing before the element has actually been rendered on the page, and jQuery can't find it. Try putting `$("#vendor_addresses").chosen();` as part of the AJAX success callback. Failing that, try commenting out the chosen() method, running the AJAX script, then manually running the chosen() method. If it works that way, you have to delay it a little bit.

EDIT:

Actually, looking more closely at your code, it appears you're using an ID tag instead of a class. Do multiple HTML elements have the #vendor_address id? If so, use a class instead, and use `$('.vendor_addresses').last().chosen();`. If you use an ID, and use an ID selector, jQuery will pick the first element if finds with that ID, and stop there.

Lesson to be learned? Use an ID for UNIQUE elements, and classes for multiple elements of the same 'class'.

Comment: It's a unique ID - the trouble is that the element in question is being injected into the page dependent on what's being selected from the first select box.  So chosen needs to be re-rendered.  It's the re-render I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Have you tried my first remedy? Running the command manually after a delay?

Comment: If you could post some HTML of the form before and after the new select box has been added, that'd be helpful as well.

Comment: I added the HTML - and I've tried your remedy (running after the delay) - it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the result of your ajax call into the DOM it's success callback, which is executed whenever it finishes (independent of the script's execution). In this case, your ajax request is being made, the code after it begins executing, and then the callback. The odds of the success callback being called before the next line of code are slim, as the ajax call is an http request which takes much longer than a line of JavaScript executing.

You want to put the code in the success call back, such as:

```
      $.ajax({
          type : "GET",
          url : "/purchaseorders/upd_vndr_locs",
          data : vndr_json,
          success: function(res) {
            overlay.hide();
            $("#vndrAddrOpts").html(res);
            $("#vendor_addresses").chosen();
          }
      });
```

Comment: I tried this as the first one of my iterations - it didn't work.